# Average Grade Calculator Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working with my project that calculates the average grade. My code works but gives me the wrong answer.

My code allows the user to enter all of his/her 'grade' and 'units'.

So example:

```
                  Grade   |   Number of Units

   Subject 1:      2.00              3
   Subject 2:      1.50              5
   Subject 3:      1.75              2
```

The calculation will be: `AVERAGE=((2.00*3)+(1.50*3)+(1.75*2) / TOTAL OF UNITS)`

```
AVERAGE = (6+4.5+3.5) / 10

AVERAGE = 1.7
```

The problem in my code is it sums up all the grades then it divides by the sum of all units.

Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/n4nkmxtx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look to this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4nkmxtx/2/

I have only changed the calculation function:

```
$("#addAll").click(function() {
    var grade = 0;
    var units = 0;

    var grades = $(".grade");
    var units = $(".units");
    var total = 0; // counts total sum of multiplications
    var unitsTotal = 0; // counts total sum of units

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        total += Number($(grades).eq(i).val()) * Number($(units).eq(i).val());
        unitsTotal += Number($(units).eq(i).val());
    }

    var average = total / unitsTotal;

    $("#para").text("Average is : " + average);
});
```

We save the array of `grade` inputs and array of `units` arrays.
Assuming they have the equal length, we iterate through them and calculate the sum of totals and the total count of units.

[**`jQuery.eq()`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) stands for getting the n-th item from a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it this way?

```
var g=(((2.00*3)+(1.50*3)+(1.75*2)));
alert(g/` TOTAL OF UNITS`);  //1.4
```

Comment: Dividing by 10 here is wrong, there are only 8 elements being averaged in your question.

Comment: @JustAnotherDotNetDev It was just for the example here,10 should be replaced by ` TOTAL OF UNITS` in this case.